# Programmatically get View Field rendered HTML

Tags: views, 8

I need to programmatically read a field output from a View in Drupal 8. The field output has been rewritten with extra text and twig. My code:

```
 foreach($view->result as $row){
    foreach ($view->field as $fieldId => $field) {
      if ($fieldId == 'Fieled 1') {
          $field_output = $view->style_plugin->getFieldValue($row->index, $fieldId);
      }
    }
  }
```

The output is a numeric value, which does not make sense to me. (The field  is a text field overwritten with a long text paragraph).
Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! As side note, `$fieldId = 'Fieled 1'` inside the `if` statement is probably not what you want. That code is just setting `$fieldID` to `'Fieled 1'`, and then always executing the code inside the `if` statement.

Comment: Sorry. It's a typo. I hope you get what I am looking for.